# Swift - How can I allow people to set their own Firebase Backend?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an iOS Swift App in which I want to allow people to create link their own Firebase backend databases to my App.

I have made successfully made my own Firebase database, but I want other developers who are interested in using my App as their frontend to tie in this with their own firebase backend.

Is this possible and if so can you give me some code samples?

Comment: They would have to export the GoogleServices-Info.plist file from their FirebaseConsole and add it to the app, change references in code from your Firebase to their Firebase, compile and run. However, there are rules, authentication etc to consider. Also, if you ever update the app, that would all have to be re-done with each release. This question is pretty vague and I am not sure what code samples you are looking for. Can you maybe clarify it so we understand the 'big picture'?

Answer (score 0):

***firebase database ios example code***

> [Firebase Database Quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/tree/master/database)

***or try watch video***

> [Getting Started with the Firebase Realtime Database on iOS -
>   Firecasts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=joVi3thZOqc)

***Article***

> [Firebase Tutorial: Getting Started IOS](https://www.raywenderlich.com/139322/firebase-tutorial-getting-started-2)
>
> [Firebase Realtime Database Tutorial for Swift using Xcode](https://www.simplifiedios.net/firebase-realtime-database-tutorial/)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, this is not what I was looking for. I clarified my question above so it should make more sense. I want developers to tie in their own Firebase backend to my App.